# How do I make a Transform object follow it's parents rotation

Tags: unity, rotation

So basically i have a transform object parented to a gun.  I use this transform to determine the position my bullets are spawned in, and their rotation.  The position part of it works fine, but the transform object doesn't follow the guns rotation. :(  I tried adding this line of code to the gun script.

(bulletPoint is a variable that references the transform object.)

```
bulletPoint.rotation = this.transform.rotation;
```

but it didn't do anything.

How do i get the transform object to follow the guns rotation? (either in code or the editor)

Thanks in advance.  :)

Edit: This is the code I have written for the gun.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rifle : MonoBehaviour
{

private int bulletSpeed = 5;
[SerializeField] Transform bulletPoint;
[SerializeField] GameObject bullet;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    bulletPoint.rotation = this.transform.rotation;
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        GameObject bulletInstance = Instantiate(bullet, bulletPoint.position, bulletPoint.rotation) as GameObject;
        bulletInstance.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, bulletSpeed);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That's weird. Rotating a parent should also rotate all its children with it automatically. There should be no code necessary to make that happen. When you spawn the bullets, do you maybe use `transform.localRotation` instead of `transform.rotation`?

Comment: no, I use transform.rotation.

Comment: The variable I access the transform from is a transform variable, not a gameObject variable.  would that make any difference?

Comment: No, that would not make a difference. Can you show us the code which rotates the parent and the code which spawns the bullets from the child?

Comment: well, the gun is parented to the standard assets first person controller.  It's a free download from the unity asset store.  I'll put my code for the gun as an edit, and if it's necessary I can put the first person controller code in as well.

Comment: It looks like your rotation is correct, but you're setting the velocity to move along the z axis regardless of the direction it's rotated. Is that intentional?

Comment: no, that is not intentional.  How am i doing that?  I set it's rotation to  wherever the transform object is rotated when it's spawned, and then give it velocity on the z axis.  how does that make it ignore the rotation?

Comment: i've decided that it's just my lack of understanding of how the fps code works.  I'll create it from scratch.